# Amadeus Self Service Test API - Flight Inspiration Search - nothing but errors

Tags: api, testing, amadeus

I have tried a number of airport codes as origin, taken from your test env list, but each and everyone results in either a 404 or a 500 error.

Is the valid code list out of date on github? In which case does anyone have a valid list i can use for testing?

On a separate note, I don't think 500 should ever be returned in scenario's equating to a 'not found'. 500 is a specific indicator of unforeseen system errors

Comment: Hi Steve, we are reviewing internally the API. We will notify you when it will be back.

Comment: I got this answer via email: "This is happening because you are using the API in the test environment. If you use production everything will work as expected"

Comment: oh dear - whats the point in a test env that doesn't work 